# send file over FTP

Tags: csv, batch-file, cmd, ftp, dos

I have a program that generates a CSV file, based on the name of the file, it has to be compressed. and sent over FTP to a differnt location

Can I please get your expert advice on how to proceed  with making the cmd file accept file name dynamically? and how to FTP a file using a CMD

Output from my program:TESTING_OUTPUT.csv  in the d:\testingfolder\

Input FILE NAME to CMD file : TESTING_OUTPUT.csv

Output : TESTING_OUTPUT.ZIP sent over FTP to 1.123.456 user -scott pwd -tiger

If i am able to make a CMD file then i want to call the CMD file from the post SQL as call d:\TESTINGFOLDER\FTP.cmd TESTING_OUTPUT.csv

can you please help me make the CMD ?

Comment: What have you tried so far? There are many examples on Google of how to FTP a file via the command line. We won't quite the code for you (well, somebody might, but they really shouldn't), but we'd be happy to correct any errors you have in your existing code. Also what do you mean by "accept a file name dynamically?"

Comment: Hi, 
I have never made cmd files before. I am a dataware-housing professional and not a coder.

Comment: dynamically accepting a file name i meant 

call cmdfilehere inputfilenamehere.csv

Comment: Ah, you're looking to use command line parameters. I recommend googling that; it's very simple and I imagine you'd get the hang of it quite quickly.

Answer (score 1):

`%1` are command line parameters in batch.

So make a batch with these lines

```
Echo %1
Echo %2
```

Then type at command prompt

```
nameofbatch.bat Parameter1 "Parameter 2"
```

Type `ftp /?` for help on ftp. Use `ftp -s:script` to execute a sequence of ftp commands. Type `ftp` then type `?` for help on the commands in the script.

You can specify a different filename by generating the script dynamically in a batch. `%1` will have the name specified on the command line.

```
echo open ftp.microsoft.com >ftp.script
echo. >>ftp.script
echo user anonymous >>ftp.script
echo email@email.com >>ftp.script
echo ls >>ftp.script
echo get softlib\%1 >>ftp.script
ftp -s:ftp.script
```

So run above batch like so

```
nameofbatfile.bat readme.txt
```

You should have a readme.txt file in the command prompt window folder.

Here's a bit more about command prompt. See the quote entry.

```
&    seperates commands on a line.

&&    executes this command only if previous command's errorlevel is 0.

||    (not used above) executes this command only if previous command's errorlevel is NOT 0

>    output to a file

>>    append output to a file

<    input from a file

|    output of one command into the input of another command

^    escapes any of the above, including itself, if needed to be passed to a program

"    parameters with spaces must be enclosed in quotes

+ used with copy to concatinate files. E.G. copy file1+file2 newfile

, used with copy to indicate missing parameters. This updates the files modified date. E.G. copy /b file1,,

%variablename% a inbuilt or user set environmental variable

!variablename! a user set environmental variable expanded at execution time, turned with SelLocal EnableDelayedExpansion command

%<number> (%1) the nth command line parameter passed to a batch file. %0 is the batchfile's name.

%* (%*) the entire command line.

%<a letter> or %%<a letter> (%A or %%A) the variable in a for loop. Single % sign at command prompt and double % sign in a batch file.
```

Comment: See? I said somebody would answer this question, despite the fact that is off topic and therefore doesn't deserve an answer.